# Can not instantiate another class from main in C++

Tags: c++, class

These are my files. I am trying to print a line using another class from main.cpp but it gives an error "**undefined reference to poddy:poddy()**"

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "poddy.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    poddy le;
    return 0;
}
```

poddy.h

```
#ifndef PODDY_H
#define PODDY_H

class poddy {
    public:
        poddy();
};

#endif // PODDY_H
```

poddy.cpp

```
#include "poddy.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

poddy::poddy() {
    cout << "I am llalala and use anoder class" << endl;
}
```

Please help me out!

Comment: What are you using to compile and link?

Comment: How are you compiling it? Btw, "using namespace std" is almost never a good thing to do.

Comment: @Joachim: So what to do instead? Write `using std::<something>;` a lot of times?

Comment: I was not working in a project in CodeBlocks, when I did it in project, it got working. Thanx everybody.

Comment: Don't ever use the word "it" in a question when it's not clear what the word refers to. The most important piece of information -- what it was that gave you the error -- was hidden by your use of the words "it gives an error". Also totally unhelpful, not specifying how far you got in the process before you got the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 4):

Your C++ code is correct. The "undefined reference" is a linker error that has to do with the way you are compiling your code. In order for it to link, use this command line:

```
g++ poddy.cpp main.cpp
```

Here are the details: the process of compiling C++ code has three major stages - preprocessing, compiling, and linking. Preprocessor deals with `#define` and `#include` statements in your code. Compiler takes the results of preprocessing, and produces binary code for each translation unit (in your case, there are two translation units - `poddy.cpp` and `main.cpp`). Finally, the linker establishes connections between parts of binary code within translation units.

The preprocessor and the compiler can do their job even when presented with one translation unit at a time. The linker, however, must "see" all translation units at once. When you call `g++` without additional flags, all stages of the compiler are invoked, including the linker. That's why you need to list all translation units at once.

Comment: Specifically, you need to specify all of your source files to the compiler.  If you're building your code without the reference to poddy.cpp on the command line, the compiler won't build it, and the linker won't know where to find the class it defines.