# C++: Undefined reference to functions

Tags: c++, g++, geany

I'm using header files, my functions aren't being recognized. The exact errors I am getting are:

main.cpp:(text+0x67): undefined reference to 'resetDeck()'

main.cpp:(text+0x6c): undefined reference to 'deal()'

main.cpp:(text+0x71): undefined reference to 'displayCards()

The functions are called in lines 18, 19, and 20 of main.cpp.
Here is the code (yes I know I spelled manager wrong):

**cardManger.h**

```
#ifndef CARDMANGER_H_INCLUDED
#define CARDMANGER_H_INCLUDED
    void resetDeck(void);
    void deal(void);
    void displayCards(void);
#endif
```

**cardManger.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "cardManger.h"
using namespace std;
int playerOneNumberOfCards = 7;
int playerTwoNumberOfCards = 7;
int playerThreeNumberOfCards = 7;
int playerFourNumberOfCards = 7;
vector<int> playerOnesHand(7);
vector<int> playerTwosHand(7);
vector<int> playerThreesHand(7);
vector<int> playerFoursHand(7);
int playerTwosCardMem[3];
int playerThreeCardMem[3];
int playerFoursCardMem[3];
int playerTwosUserMem[3];
int playerThreeUserMem[3];
int playerFoursUserMem[3];
int playerTwoMemCount;
int playerThreeMemCount;
int playerFourMemCount;
int deck[52];
void resetDeck(void){
    deck[0] = 1;
    deck[1] = 1;
    deck[2] = 1;
    deck[3] = 1;
    deck[4] = 2;
    deck[5] = 2;
    deck[6] = 2;
    deck[7] = 2;
    deck[8] = 3;
    deck[9] = 3;
    deck[10] = 3;
    deck[11] = 3;
    deck[12] = 4;
    deck[13] = 4;
    deck[14] = 4;
    deck[15] = 4;
    deck[16] = 5;
    deck[17] = 5;
    deck[18] = 5;
    deck[19] = 5;
    deck[20] = 6;
    deck[21] = 6;
    deck[22] = 6;
    deck[23] = 6;
    deck[25] = 7;
    deck[26] = 7;
    deck[27] = 7;
    deck[28] = 8;
    deck[29] = 8;
    deck[30] = 8;
    deck[31] = 8;
    deck[32] = 9;
    deck[33] = 9;
    deck[34] = 9;
    deck[35] = 9;
    deck[36] = 10;
    deck[37] = 10;
    deck[38] = 10;
    deck[39] = 10;
    deck[40] = 11;
    deck[41] = 11;
    deck[42] = 11;
    deck[43] = 11;
    deck[44] = 12;
    deck[45] = 12;
    deck[46] = 12;
    deck[47] = 12;
    deck[48] = 13;
    deck[49] = 13;
    deck[50] = 13;
    deck[51] = 13;
}
void deal (void){
    srand(time(0));
    int r;
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 8; i>0; i--){
        if(i == 8){
            playerOnesHand[7] = 0;
        }else{
            do{
                s = (rand()%51)+1;
                r = deck[s];
            }while(r == 0); 
            playerOnesHand[--i] = r;
            i++;
            deck[s] = 0;
        }

    }
    s = 0;
    r = 0;

    for(int i = 8; i>0; i--){
        if(i == 8){
            playerTwosHand[7] = 0;
        }else{
            do{
                s = (rand()%51)+1;
                r = deck[s];
            }while(r == 0); 
            playerTwosHand[--i] = r;
            i++;
            deck[s] = 0;
        }

    }
    s = 0;
    r = 0;
    for(int i = 8; i>0; i--){
        if(i == 8){
            playerThreesHand[7] = 0;
        }else{
            do{
                s = (rand()%51)+1;
                r = deck[s];
            }while(r == 0); 
            playerThreesHand[--i] = r;
            i++;
            deck[s] = 0;
        }

    }
    s = 0;
    r = 0;
    for(int i = 8; i>0; i--){
        if(i == 8){
            playerFoursHand[7] = 0;
        }else{
            do{
                s = (rand()%51)+1;
                r = deck[s];
            }while(r == 0); 
            playerFoursHand[--i] = r;
            i++;
            deck[s] = 0;
        }

    }
}
void displayCards(void){
    for(int i = playerOneNumberOfCards; i > 0; i--){
        cout << playerOnesHand[i];
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ai.h"
#include "cardManger.h"
using namespace std;
int numberOfPlayers;
bool gameIsOn;
string question;
/* Allocates memory for players*/

int main(void){
    std::cout << "Welcome to Go Fish. Do you wish to play? If so enter Y. If not enter N. \n";
    std::cin >> question;
    if((question == "N") || (question == "n")){
        return 0;
    }
    gameIsOn = true;
    do{
        resetDeck();
        deal();
        displayCards();
        gameIsOn = false;
    }while(gameIsOn);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you linking in your `cardManger.cpp`? Is it part of your project?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16882098/335858. It looks like you're experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Do you know how to link files in Geany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered what was wrong. I didn't link my files with a makefile.  Thank you for all the comments.